# Automatically moving map with reference to other Map

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-api-3

Hi this is my site in which when I enter a location I see the opposite side of the world in the second map.  I want to synchronize the two maps such that when the user moves the map1,  map2 automatically moves to follow.  I tried a lot but its not working there. Here is the [link to my page](http://usman123.phpnet.us/remo/)  Please anyone who can tell me what should I do? You can view the source code also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the center_changed event and the getCenter/setCenter methods.

Maybe something like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map1,'center_changed', function () {
    var newCenter = map1.getCenter();
    var opppositePosition = getOppositePosition(newCenter);
    map2.setCenter(oppositePosition);
});

function getOppositePosition(originalPosition) {
    return new google.maps.LatLng(newCenter.lat() * -1, newCenter.lng() * -1);
}
```

I don't know if my `getOppositePosition` function returns the right position - is the opposite position on the earth the place with opposite lat and lng like this? If not, try implementing the function in a different way.

Comment: If you see my code i divide the maps into divs and i draw the maps using map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas_new"), myOptions); statement.I divide my code into functions,then where sould i write this?

Comment: One way would be to store both maps as global variables. Then initialize code like I wrote above when the user presses the 'locate' button (after the second map is drawn.)